# RStudio error message - the device does not recognize the command

Tags: r, rstudio

I am repeatedly getting the error message:

Error Save File: ' The device does not recognize the command' popping up over and over (every 15 seconds) - even when I don't click save or when I do click save.

I also can't load a R file that is in my folder - I have to open it up in notepad and copy it paste it to even see it.

Can someone let me know how to fix this?  I have the latest version of Rstudio installed.

Comment: [RStudio support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/202199118--Save-file-The-device-does-not-recognize-the-command-) says this may be due to running out of disk space.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the drive memory runs out of space. As a quick fix measure, try copying all the code to an another R script file/ notepad and you might save it luckily. Long term solution would be to clear the cache and upgrade your hard drive..

Comment: It does not look to be related with disk space. I have plenty, however, I am getting the message. I could copy all text from a script, create new script and save with the same file name.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you are reading from a file that is open in another program in some cases. Generally speaking R has no issues reading in files that are open / read only (i.e. import a CSV file) if that file is in use by another process. However, there are some cases where the read-only restriction from a locked file being imported causes the

> Error Save File: ' The device does not recognize the command'

message to persist even if you are not trying to to read from or write to the locked file.

As a specific example, if you are using openxlsx to import an xlsx file that you are also viewing in excel, after reading the xlsx file in, you will get the error whenever you make changes to your R script and stop for more than a few seconds, or when you try to save the R script, even though it is not touching the xlsx file. However, if you close R Studio and re-open your script, you will notice that the issue will not appear until you try to read the xlsx file in again.

Answer (score 0):

Met error "The device does not recognise the command" today. Not due to disc space but due to an r script that was somehow no good, even though file extension OK. After a very frustrating time when I couldn't copy to a fresh R script or shut down the project, saved content of troublesome r script to another older r script, deleted it  and all OK - e.g. could now open up another new script that saved with no problems.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).